# Bots - detecting JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, bots

Can Bots figure out JavaScript sections of a webpage? Would it be possible for them to parse through the source code of a webpage (I am guessing the dynamic scripts will show up in the source code) and determine javascript events.

Also, I am curious if bots can do this in any other way apart from merely parsing the source code. For example, say there is a script which populates a text field with a random string, whenever a user clicks on a button. By merely parsing the page source, a bot cannot determine what the string will be (since there is just a rand() function). So can the bot in any way guess the actual contents of the string that is entered into the text field.

P.S: I am a grad student researching on web bot detection techniques.

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if a specific viewer is a bot?  Or are you trying to hide information from bots?

Comment: I am trying to detect if a specific viewer is a bot.

Comment: So, from your server, you're trying to detect if a particular page request is coming from a bot?  If no javascript is executed in your page, you can't detect anything from the page itself.

Answer (score 5):

First of all bots are very unlikely to even execute any javascript on your page.  With so many zillions of web pages on the internet, it's generally easier to just go scan more web pages than linger trying to solve issues on web pages that only expose content via javascript.

Second, a generic bot is not going to know how your web page works and is not going to know what needs to be where before doing some operation on your page.  They scrape and parse what they find looking for things of interest.  If a URL was in your script as a full URL, they might be smart enough to find that.  But, if a URL was built from pieces in your script, it's extremely unlikely than any generic bot would be able to figure out that your code was putting together a URL and what it would be.

Third, a specific attacker could analyze your page, figure out how it works and design a way to circumvent certain user operations.  But, that's only if some attacker decides to specifically attack/circumvent your site.  No generic bot that hasn't been specifically code to your site is going to be able to do that.  That's where captcha type operations come into the picture because it's very hard for a script to "read" images to get codes out of them that have to then be submitted to a server - so even bots built for a specific purpose can't really solve captcha-type problems.  They can use real people to solve captcha problems, but now it's starting to cost them money and few sites would be worth that.  The idea with a lot of these obstacles is to just make the cost of circumventing them more than the benefit of getting in.  The snoops are in it to make money so they run the other way when it costs more than they can make.

Fourth, you asked about "events".  Keep in mind that there are programmatic events (timers, page load events, etc...) and there are user events.  Programmatic events will occur only if there is a browser to cause them or if javascript code is executed in a browser-like environment.  User events (keys, clicks, mouse movements, etc...) will only occur if there is a browser-like environment in which to interact with the web page and if there is an actual user to create those events.  None of these are typically present when a bot reads your page.  They use a server-side script to fetch the page and they parse it.  They could programmatically drive a browser to load your page and create some of the programmatic events, but there still wouldn't be a user present to create any user events.  If a bot knew what user events it was supposed to simulate (button click, for example), it could drive the controlled browser to do that, but at that point, this is not a generic bot in any fashion, but a bot designed specifically to attack your site.  If one wants to go to that trouble, it's probably far easier to just engineer how one requests the desired content from your site (so it can just request it direction) rather than try to simulate an actual browser page that does so.

---

If you want to try to detect (from your web server) if something accessing your web page is likely a bot or human, all you can do is to study their access patterns from one page to the next.  Bots will "crawl" your site in some programmatic fashion.

- Bots will typically have fairly regular access patterns (a certain amount of time between each page access).  Real users are likely to have very different access patterns.
- Bots will typically not interact with controls on your page (buttons, fields, etc...) and not cause things to happen that only happen when those controls are used, so no URLs that you might create programmatically when those controls are used would be accessed.
- Bots will not know to follow written directions on the page.  They will just try to access direct links that they find in the page.
- Bots will likely follow links that are never visible - humans usually don't.  So, if you see a quick access pattern from your main page to a link that is in your page, but always invisible (CSS style rule display: none), then it's unlikely a human did that.  It's probably some programmatic agent (e.g. a bot).  So, you can set traps for bots like this that humans won't go to.

Comment: +1 - noting that a bot can do anything a browser can so it *could* figure out the script component if it wanted, but as you say likely not worth the time and effort unless a target with enough value was identified (e.g. a banking page). Also, to defeat capture, I believe there are human-based services that return the string in a few seconds for a few cents per hit. Again, it's about cost/benefit.

Comment: They could at list do the `onload` event, which I think, Google's bot does.

Comment: Since I am doing this as part of an academic project, I keep out the cost and practicality of doing this. So, basically a very intelligent bot could in theory resemble a browser and generate user and programmatic events. However would it be possible for this sophisticated bot to actually get the string (randomly generated)? I think not.

Comment: Keep in mind that a web page is just a pile of text.  It doesn't do anything by itself.  To get an onload event, you need something that downloads that text, parses that text into something that makes sense, executes appropriate javascript in the page and then triggers an onload event to happen at an appropriate time which can then let the javascript code run.  At this point, you'd need much of the functionality of a browser engine.  Bots could be build that would do that, but there are few financially justified reasons for doing so.

Comment: If a bot was driving a whole browser engine and it was specifically programmed for your site, it could be programmed to do anything a user could do except reason/think.  So, it could be programmed to press a button, then pull a number out of a field that you generated randomly, then click a link, etc...  This is why people use things like captchas that require some reasoning/advanced visual recognition to defeat a pure bot.

Comment: I added some more to my answer about tracking bot access patterns and contrasting those to human access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

No bots cannot guess the random string generated by javascript.